# C#: No implict conversion from Class<Child> to Class<Base>

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, language-features, language-design

Following snippet wouldn't compile. With following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Container<ChildClass>' to 'Container<BaseClass>'

```
class BaseClass {}
class ChildClass : BaseClass {}
class Container<T> where T : BaseClass {}
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        // why doesn't this work?
        Container<BaseClass> obj = new Container<ChildClass>(); 
    }
}
```

Is this by design? If it is, what is the reason?

Comment: This issue predictably comes up once a week or so.

Comment: ... and then Marc Gravell predictably tells everyone that covariance support in C# 4 is limited :)

Comment: Well, it *is* limited! I get tired of reading "but it'll work in C# 4.0", which just isn't true... (for lists, at least)

Comment: And this is why we need per-tag FAQs: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/138261-allow-a-per-tag-home-faq-page

Comment: so why didn't anyone post a link to a duplicate post yet? ;)

Comment: Well, in case of... angst, I've wiki'd my answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(made wiki, in case of dups)

C# (3.0) doesn't support covariance of lists etc. C# 4.0 will support **limited** [co|contra]variance, but [still not lists](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/02/what-c-40-covariance-doesn-do.html).

The problem is that with:

```
Container<BaseClass> obj = new Container<ChildClass>();
```

I could do:

```
obj.Add(new SomeOtherSubclass()); // SomeOtherSubclass : BaseClass
```

which would compile, but not work.

This behaviour *is* supported for arrays, but largely for historic reasons.

Comment: A friend of mine complained about lack of covariance like a year ago when generics first came out. I had no idea what he was talking about. Then I tried to do the above... I should listen to him more often.

Answer (score 4):

Yo,

If you want the killer article on covariance/contravariance on C#, check out the eric lippert blog, "fabulous adventures in coding". First, this is my favortie blog's name, and second eric wrote the best sequence of articles on (co|contra)variance:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx

This is as good as [Breaking Bad](http://epguides.com/BreakingBad/).

Comment: I take back this one, and trade it for this:
this is as good as breaking bad, season 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is what's knows as covariance / contravariance which isn't available as of C# 3.0. It will be somewhat available in C# 4.0. Here's some info:

http://reddevnews.com/articles/2009/05/01/generic-covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-40.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot implicitly convert type `Container<ChildClass>` to `Container<BaseClass>`

There is a very common mis-conception that `MyClass<Child>` inherits from `MyClass<Base>`.