# C# Type Conversion Error Despite Generic Constraint

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion, covariance, constraints

Why, with a generic constraint on type parameter T of class P of "must inherit from A", does the first call succeed but the second call fail with the type conversion error detailed in the comment:

```
abstract class A { }

static class S
{
    public static void DoFirst(A argument) { }
    public static void DoSecond(ICollection<A> argument) { }
}

static class P<T>
    where T : A, new()
{
    static void Do()
    {
        S.DoFirst(new T());             // this call is OK

        S.DoSecond(new List<T>());      // this call won't compile with:

        /* cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'
           to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<A>' */
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the generic constraint ensure that `List<T>` *is* indeed `ICollection<A>`?

Comment: Closing as dupe - please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981570/c-no-implict-conversion-from-classchild-to-classbase

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an example of C#'s lack of [covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) on generic types (C# *does* support array covariance). C# 4 will add this feature on interface types and also will update several BCL interface types to support it as well.

Please see [C# 4.0: Covariance and Contravariance](http://blog.t-l-k.com/dot-net/2009/c-sharp-4-covariance-and-contravariance):

> In this article I’ll try to cover one
>   of the C# 4.0 innovations. One of the
>   new features is covariance and
>   contravariance on type parameters that
>   is now supported by generic delegates
>   and generic interfaces. First let’s
>   see what does these words mean :)

Comment: This will not change in C# 4.0. `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>` are _not covariant_. So even though C# 4.0 will add support for type covariance, this particular case will keep not working.

Comment: Pavel, you seem to be confused here. The types in play are NOT IList<T> and ICollection<T>...they are List<T> (the concrete type, not the interface) and ICollection<T>. A List<T> is ABSOLUTELY an ICollection<T>, and that does make them covariant. You posted your comment in THREE posts, and apparently downvoted two of them...based on the wrong type...its not IList<T>, its List<T>!

Answer (score 0):

The constraint has no effect on the problem; the issue is that you're passing a List in a parameter that requires ICollection--C# doesn't support covariance so you need to explicitly cast the list to an ICollection:

```
S.DoSecond((ICollection<A>) new List<T>());      // this call will be happy
```

Comment: The problem isn't `IList`/`ICollection` mismatch, the problem is type argument mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

You have strongly typed the parameter for DoSecond as type ICollection<A>. Despite the fact that T is of type A, at compile time there is no **implicit** cast between List<T> and ICollection<A>. You will either need to create the list and cast it to ICollection<A> when you call DoSecond, or make DoSecond a generic method itself.

NOTE: This type of implicit cast should be supported in C# 4.0, which will provide much improved co/contravariance over what C# 3.0 offers.

Comment: Er yes, there is an implicit upcast between T and A. There is no upcast between `IList<T>` and `IList<A>`. Also, covariance support in C# 4.0 won't help here, because neither `IList<T>` nor `ICollection<T>` are covariant in and of themselves.

Comment: I edited my post to clarify my meaning. The types used were List<T> and ICollection<A>. List<T> is indeed an ICollection<T>, and since T is of A, ICollection<T> should be covariant with ICollection<A> in C# 4.0. I apologize for the original lack of clarity...hopefully my edit makes it more clear.