# Function Declarations with Generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a function that is declared like so:

```
public static string MultiWhereToString(List<WhereCondition<T>> whereConditions)
```

I am trying to pass it a variable called `whereAnd` which is delcared like so:

```
private List<WhereAndCondition<T>> whereAnd = new List<WhereAndCondition<T>>();
```

`WhereAndCondition` is a sub class of `WhereCondition`. It is declared like so:

```
public class WhereAndCondition<T> : WhereCondition<T>, IConditional where T : DatabaseObject
```

My issue is, if I try to execute the following code:

```
private List<WhereAndCondition<T>> whereAnd = new List<WhereAndCondition<T>>();
MultiWhereToString(whereAnd);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BrainStorm.WhereAndCondition<T>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BrainStorm.WhereCondition<T>>'
```

Any ideas on why? I think it has to do with the generics of the `WhereCondition` classes.

Comment: Can you `public static string MultiWhereToString(IList<ICondition<T>> whereConditions)` ?

Comment: [In C#, is it possible to cast a List<Child> to List<Parent>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777800/in-c-is-it-possible-to-cast-a-listchild-to-listparent)

Comment: If you were to pass around IEnumerable instead of List, you could take advantage of covariance features. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Comment: @MichałPowaga No. There isn't a way to guarantee proper use.

Comment: @McKay: It's a link to a duplicate.

Comment: @Inerdia Oh, it is. It looked just like a question. My bad.

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory Thats actually what I wound up doing. Worked nicely

Comment: I put it down as an answer, feel free to mark it or not. Glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using interfaces:

```
public static string MultiWhereToString(IEnumerable<ICondition<T>> whereConditions)
```

This would allow you a lot more freedom when calling this method.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
class A {}
class A : B {}
```

An object of `List<B>` is **not** an instance of `List<A>`. So you can't cast a `List<WhereAndCondition>` to a `List<WhereCondition>`. You could use:

```
MultiWhereToString(whereAnd.OfType<WhereCondition>().ToList());
```

(There might also be a solution involving the `in` and `out` variance annotations, but I'm not terribly familiar with them.)

Answer (score 2):

Your function is defined as taking a WhereCondition List, but you're passing it a WhereAndCondition List:

`MultiWhereToString(List<WhereCondition<T>> whereConditions)`

```
private List<WhereAndCondition<T>> whereAnd = new List<WhereAndCondition<T>>(); 
MultiWhereToString(whereAnd);
```

List variance has limited supported in .NET 4. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981570/c-no-implict-conversion-from-classchild-to-classbase).

Comment: The reason is the fact the cast is simply not typesafe – where does loss of data come into it?

Comment: @Inerdia - I realized that as soon as I posted; I had a brain fart and was thinking of converting a parent to child, rather than the other way around. Edited with link to a better explanation than I could easily provide. And I realize that 'data loss' isn't really the correct term for that either. My language skills are garbage.

Answer (score 2):

Generics have to be known explicitly at compile time because they are generated.

Why not use:

```
private List<WhereCondition<T>> whereAnd = new List<WhereCondition<T>>();
```

So you can still add `WhereAndCondition` objects to `whereAnd`.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the entire `WhereCondition<T>` in your `MultiWhereToString` method with another generic type which is restricted to `WhereCondition<T>`.

Replace:

```
public static string MultiWhereToString(List<WhereCondition<T>> whereConditions)
```

With:

```
public static string MultiWhereToString<TType>(List<TType> whereConditions) where TType: WhereCondition<T>
```

Or alternatively change:

```
private List<WhereAndCondition<T>> whereAnd = new List<WhereAndCondition<T>>();
```

to:

```
private List<WhereCondition<T>> whereAnd = new List<WhereCondition<T>>();
```

And let inheritance take care of the rest for you.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a covariance / contravariance issue.

Simplified to this:

```
    public class WhereCondition
    {
    }

    public class WhereAndCondition : WhereCondition
    {
    }

    public class blah
    {
        public static void Blah()
        {
            List<WhereAndCondition> whereAnd = new List<WhereAndCondition>();
            MultiWhereToString(whereAnd);
        }

        public static string MultiWhereToString(List<WhereCondition> whereConditions)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

It's not going to work, because the list of WhereAndConditions can't be cast to List of WhereConditions:

Imagine it this way. You've got a list of giraffes, and the method is asking for a list of animals.

Without knowing what they are going to do with the list animals (like try adding a horse) the types are incompatible, but if you change it to something like this:

```
        public static string MultiWhereToString(IEnumerable<WhereCondition> whereConditions)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Then the variance can kick in, and give you what you're looking for.